# einsum on a sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix, sparse-array

It seems numpy's `einsum` function does not work with `scipy.sparse` matrices. Are there alternatives to do the sorts of things `einsum` can do with sparse matrices?

In response to @eickenberg's answer: The particular einsum I'm wanting to is `numpy.einsum("ki,kj->ij",A,A)` - the sum of the outer products of the rows.

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives, but there's no general "sparse einsum". It depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A restriction of `scipy.sparse` matrices is that they represent linear operators and are thus kept two dimensional, which leads to the question: Which operation are you seeking to do?

All `einsum` operations on a pair of 2D matrices are very easy to write without `einsum` using `dot`, `transpose` and pointwise operations, provided that the result does not exceed two dimensions.

So if you need a specific operation on a number of sparse matrices, it is probable that you can write it without `einsum`.

**UPDATE**: A specific way to implement `np.einsum("ki, kj -> ij", A, A)` is `A.T.dot(A)`. In order to convince yourself, please try the following example:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
a = rng.randn(3, 3)
b = rng.randn(3, 3)
the_einsum_ab = np.einsum("ki, kj -> ij", a, b)
the_a_transpose_times_b = a.T.dot(b)
# We write a test in order to assert equality
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal
assert_array_equal(the_einsum_ab, the_a_transpose_times_b)  # This passes, so equality
```

This result is slightly more general. Now if you use `b = a` you obtain your specific result.

Comment: I've added a specific example to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I addressed it in the update. Does this work for you?

Comment: yep, obvious really, when you think about it! Thx (:

Comment: What about something like `einsum('ij,ik->ijk', X, X).reshape(n, -1)`, that each the row-wise outer product?

Answer (score 4):

`einsum` translates the index string into a calculation using the C version of `np.nditer`.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html  is a nice introduction to `nditer`.  Note especially the `Cython` example at the end.

https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum/blob/master/einsum_py.py is a Python simulation of the `einsum`.

`scipy.sparse` has its own code (ultimately in C) to perform the basic operations, summation, matrix multiplication, etc.  Sparse matricies have their own data structures.  They can be lists, dictionaries, or a set of numpy arrays.  Numpy notation can be used because `sparse` has the appropriate `__xxx__` methods.

A sparse matrix is a `matrix`, a 2d array object. A sparse `einsum` could be written, but it would end up using the sparse matrix multiplication, not `nditer`.  So at best it would be a notational convenience.

Sparse `csr_matrix.dot` is:

```
def dot(self, other):
    """Ordinary dot product
    ...
    """
    return self * other

A=sparse.csr_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
A.dot(A.T).A
(A*A.T).A
A.__rmul__(A.T).A
A.__mul__(A.T).A
np.einsum('ij,kj',A.A,A.A)
# array([[ 5, 11],
#        [11, 25]])
```

Comment: Can the "optimize=True" parameter in einsum somehow optimize sparse operations? I work a lot with np.einsum, in many dimensions where many of them are mostly sparse.

Comment: @BernardoCosta, `einsum` does not deal with sparsity.  It doesn't work with `scipy.sparse` matrices, and doesn't examine the dense arrays for sparsity either.  Its `optimize` mode looks at the order of calculation when given more than 2 arrays.  As the docs say, look at `einsum_path` for more details on that.  `einsum` has changed since I first wrote this answer; it now has more in common with the `np.matmul/@`. function